# Inverse image of closed set (example)

Tags: real-analysis

There is a theorem that states that if $f$ is a continuous mapping from $X$ to $Y$ then   $f^{-1}[C]$ is closed in $X$ whenever $C$ is closed in $Y$.

I was thinking on a simple constant function defined from $(-\infty, 2)$  to $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = 4$

So, if I consider the closed set $\{4\}$ the inverse image of this set is $(-\infty, 2)$, right?  But $(-\infty, 2)$ is not closed, so believe I am missing something very important here.

Thanks in advance for the guidance.

Comment: As a hint you should consider your topology on the space $X=(-\infty,2)$.

Comment: Your domain is (-$\infty$, 2) which is closed in itself. The set is not closed in R but we don't need it here.

Comment: "closed in  itself" is the part I was missing. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You consider the map $f:(-\infty,2)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:x \mapsto 4$ where $(-\infty,2)$ has the subspace topology inherited from the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. But then the set $f^{-1}(\left\{4\right\})=(-\infty,2)$ is closed in itself.

You can only talk about the continuity of a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, so you needed to fix a topology on $(-\infty,2)$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much. I wasn't aware of that topological spaces requirement when talking of continuity. Thanks.

Comment: A continuous function is defined as a map $f$ such that the inverse image of open is open. Or equivalently the inverse image of closed is closed. Perhaps you defined continuity in terms of metric spaces (which are special topological spaces), in that setting you still have to view $(-\infty,2)$ as a metric space and it is closed in itself.

Comment: Hummm you are right. The Lemma I read uses metric spaces. Thanks!